# Getting Id of a .net dropdownlist in javascript on client click

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I need to get the ID of a dropdownlist (ASP.Net Control) So that I can tell if an item has been selected.

Right now I am trying to just write the count of the dropdownlist to an alert box as follows:

```
OnClientClick="alert(document.getElementID('<%=ListBox1.ClientID %>').options.length)
```

The error I get is 'document required.'

Answer (score 2):

First let's correct the `getElementID` in your code to `getElementById`:

```
OnClientClick="alert(document.getElementById('<%=ListBox1.ClientID %>').options.length);"
```

If you want to know which item is selected, use the `selectedIndex` property:

```
OnClientClick="alert(document.getElementById('<%=ListBox1.ClientID %>').selectedIndex);"
```

If you want the value of the option rather than the index, use the options collection with the index:

```
OnClientClick="var s=document.getElementById('<%=ListBox1.ClientID %>');alert(s.options[s.selectedIndex].value);"
```

Edit:
This would work if the control where you are trying to use it was not a server control, for example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('<%=ListBox1.ClientID %>').options.length);" />
```

As you have a server control, you can't use a script tag (<%= %>) inside the control. You have to set the property from code behind:

```
TheButton.OnClientClick = "alert(document.getElementById('" + ListBox1.ClientID + "').options.length);";
```

Comment: Still getting Object Required.

Comment: I see. It's the <%= %> script tag that is the matter. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas use document.getElementById instead of document.getElementId

Answer (score 0):

My javascript is a bit rusty but can't you use the "this" keyword? 
something like:

```
OnClientClick="alert(this.options.length);"
```